# Render sitecore page in XML?

Tags: sitecore

Is there a way to render a sitecore page in XML?  With our current setup compiling from source and pushing the code is very risky.  I need to develop an XML from a page I already have set up.  I've googled and didn't find much.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by rendering a page in XML? Do you want to include the content of a certain page in XML? Do you want to make sure that the html of your page is a valid XML? Do you want to get the set of a fields from your page in an XML format?

Comment: I want to get the set of fields from my page in an XML format.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick and dirty API script to get your fields and values given an item this should work (caveat no access to Sitecore ATM so untested):

```
  // you could use Sitecore.Context.Item here if it is the current item you want XML for
  Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(
              "{YOUR GUID HERE}");
  item.Fields.ReadAll();
  var fields = item.Fields.ToList();
  XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                 new XDeclaration("1.0", null, null),
                 new XElement("Export",
                     fields.Select(
                                 field => new XElement(
                                     field.Name,
                                     field.Value)
                             )
                     ));

  Response.Write(doc.ToString());
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Sitecore Item Web API to get content in XML or JSON. Here's a reference:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you login to : /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx with an admin account, select the item that you want to see like XML, and in right part you have View XML, and you can copy all fields in XML format.

Also if you want to see on the page you can use:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$sc_currentitem" />
```

Comment: Can i just put that code right on the page and go to the .xsl extension?

Comment: You can put that code on an xslt file and to call in aspx page or ascx  control with : <xsl:include  href = "uri-reference"/>

Comment: I think we may have a problem with the xslt rendering.  This site is pretty locked down with how they have it set up.

Comment: Can you deploy any files at all? You can just create an aspx with all the required on the page set to "compile at runtime" for that single page. That may be your best bet. Even if you don't have direct access, you can upload the file using the File Manager in Sitecore Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an alternate device. An sitecore device (see documentation) enables different presentations for one contentitem. often used for mobile and rss, but we use it for JSON and XML as wel. Just implement a special layout/sublayout to generate the xml. You are free to use serialization or plan aspx/cshtml to create the xml.